# Storing each row of a CSV as a separate list/dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm new to programming, and I am attempting to parse a pipe-delimited CSV file, and store each item row (each row after the header) in a separate list or dictionary.

```
import csv
with open('toverdpython.csv', 'rb') as toverd:
    reader = csv.reader(toverd, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    
    rownum = 0
    i = 1

    for row in reader:
        #Save header row
        if rownum == 0:
            inputHeader = row
        else: 
            inputRow = {}
            inputRow[i] = row
            i + 1
            print(inputRow.items())
            
       
        rownum+=1

    toverd.close()
```

This is generating an output of:

```
[(2, ['"Test 8"', '"Test 8"', '', '"Test 8"', 'IUGIGUGUI', 'A', 'EA', '602132312952', '2',      'Default', '', '', '', '', '', '"Test 8"', '6123142', 'US', '', '', '', '', '2121231234', '', 'A', '00002', '4600018168', '1', 'A', '0', 'USD', '10026178', '"KGIUGUGIGIU"', 'SADH', '', '', ''])]
[(2, ['"Test 9"', '"Test 9"', '', '"Test 9"', 'BIGIUG802', 'A', 'EA', '6123124242', '2', 'Default', '', '', '', '', '', '"Test 9"', '3694498', 'US', '', '', '', '', '51124124'', 'A', '00002', '463325358', '1', 'A', '0', 'USD', '134345436178', '"MNONOINOIN"', 'SADAHRH', '', '', ''])]
```

The data is correct, but I'm having difficulty telling if I am overwriting my information with each iteration of the loop. I tried reading up on both lists and dictionaries, but I feel as if I'm totally lost.

The goal is for me to be able to store each row of the document in a separate array, like maybe inputRow1[], InputRow2[], etc, and reference values in each line by position, like inputRow2[3] should return "Test 9".

Comment: unfortunately, you are just discarding every inputRow. You say you want inputRow1[], inputRow2{}, etc... but normally we deal with a list of rows like inputRow[1][], etc... is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
import csv
with open('toverdpython.csv', 'rb') as toverd:
    reader = csv.reader(toverd, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    
    # get the header
    inputHeader = next(reader)    

    # get the rest
    inputRows = [row for row in reader]

# just to vreify...
print inputHeader
for row in inputRows:
    print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted- the "row for row in reader" syntax was so succinct that I had a hard time understanding what it was doing... thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, list comprehensions can be puzzling but cool to show off to your friends later.

Comment: header is an unknown variable in your code. Can you explain what do you mean by ```print header```

Comment: @LibinThomas - I didn't use the correct variable name. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the inputRaw dictionary like a list, so you may be better off just using a list e.g. `inputRaw = []`

You need to put `inputRow = []` before the for loop otherwise you are overwriting it in every iteration.

Also initialize `i = 0` before the loop because lists are zero based.

You may want to look at csv.DictReader in https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely have a look at DictReader.